# Enabling Hive Cache and facing errors

Tags: hive, aws-glue, presto, trino

I am trying to enable hive cache in Presto using following configuration as below

```
hive.cache.enabled=true
hive.cache.location=/opt/hive-cache
```

However I am getting error when coordinator starts up

```
   20-12-09T21:07:22.229Z  INFO    main    com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore Loading catalog glue
   2020-12-09T21:07:23.019Z    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

   1) Configuration property 'hive.cache.enabled' was not used
 at com.facebook.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:244)

   2) Configuration property 'hive.cache.location' was not used
   at 

com.facebook.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:244)

2 errors
com.google.inject.CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) Configuration property 'hive.cache.enabled' was not used
 at com.facebook.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:244)

2) Configuration property 'hive.cache.location' was not used
 at com.facebook.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.lambda$initialize$2(Bootstrap.java:244)

2 errors
   at com.google.inject.internal.Errors.throwCreationExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:543)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.initializeStatically(InternalInjectorCreator.java:159)
   at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:106)
   at com.google.inject.Guice.createInjector(Guice.java:87)
   at com.facebook.airlift.bootstrap.Bootstrap.initialize(Bootstrap.java:251)
   at com.facebook.presto.hive.HiveConnectorFactory.create(HiveConnectorFactory.java:136)
   at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnector(ConnectorManager.java:379)
   at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.addCatalogConnector(ConnectorManager.java:231)
   at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:223)
   at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:209)
   at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalog(StaticCatalogStore.java:123)
   at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalog(StaticCatalogStore.java:98)
   at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalogs(StaticCatalogStore.java:80)
   at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalogs(StaticCatalogStore.java:68)
   at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:138)
   at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:79)
```

I am using PrestoDB and Glue

Answer (score 2):

The [Hive Storage Caching](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/hive-caching.html) and the related configuration property `hive.cache.enabled` was introduced in Presto 332. Make sure you run this version or newer. The latest currently available is 347, see https://trino.io/download.html.